# Determine highest, second highest, third highest values in an array with specific child types?

Tags: c#, arrays, parent-child

I have an array of abstract class Athlete.

```
    {
        athletes[0] = new BobSledder("Bobby", "Ben and Bill");
        athletes[1] = new BobSledder("Burt", "Bonnie and Baek");
        athletes[2] = new BobSledder("Barnie", "Blues and  Bart");
        athletes[3] = new Skier("Sally", "downhill");
        athletes[4] = new Skier("Sarah", "downhill");
        athletes[5] = new Skier("Sam", "downhill");
        athletes[6] = new IceSkater("Suzy", "blue");
        athletes[7] = new IceSkater("Sullie", "red");
        athletes[8] = new IceSkater("Sierra", "orange");

    }
```

There is a field called averageScore in the Athlete class. I have child classes based off Athlete for each different child type. I want to be able to find the top 3 averageScores of each child type in the array. If more athletes were added I want to be able to still only find the top 3. How would I go about doing that? I'm sorry, I'm fairly new to programming and I've never used child types before. I don't know where to begin.

```
 public abstract class Athlete
{
    string name;
    int eventsRun;
    int lastScore;
    int runningTotal;
    double averageScore;

    public Athlete()
    {
    }

    public Athlete(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public int EventsRun { get { return eventsRun; } }
    public int LastScore
    {
        get { return lastScore; }
        set
        {
            lastScore = value;
            eventsRun++;
            runningTotal += lastScore;
            averageScore = runningTotal / eventsRun;
        }
    }
    public double AverageScore { get { return averageScore; } }
```

Comment: @d2894.. what is averageScore.. show code snippet of that

Comment: Advise for the future: do not duplicate tags in title. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for info. :)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 3.5 or above:

```
var topThreePerSubtype = athletes.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.averageScores).Take(3));
```

This will actually return an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<Athlete>`, which is probably not the best. I'd suggest that you use a TopThree class or the like to property represent the resulting instances.

Here's an (oversimplified) example:

```
public class TopThree
{
    public Type SubType {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Athlete> Athletes {get; set;}
}

(...)

var topThreePerSubtype = athletes.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(g => new TopThree() { SubType = g.Key, Athletes = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.AverageScores).Take(3)});
```

What's great about this approach is that **even if you add a whole new discipline it will be able to create yet another top three object for you**. No additional code will be required.

Of course since this makes use of LINQ extensions you must make sure you have this on top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Beat me by just a few seconds

Comment: @user1477388 You can answer on how to do it prior to 3.5, that's still useful info. (I'm too lazy to do it myself :) )

Comment: This doesn't quite answer what the OP is looking for, which is: "I want to be able to find the top 3 averageScores of `each child type` in the array."

Comment: This still doesn't do it. You need to take the top 3 of each sub class. In his example array, you would actually return all 9 scores. Because there are 3 groups of 3 classes.

Comment: Either I'm missing something or the OP is unclear or doesn't show enough code. In his model the AverageScore is a property for the Athlete class, there's no sub type of any kind.

Comment: <facepalm/> I get it now. :p

Comment: There, this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

First I would use a list of athletes, not an array since you want to be able to change the number of athletes and arrays should only be used when the number inside of them won't change.

So then you have:

```
List<Athlete> athletes = new List<Athlete>{/*Whatever athlete's you're adding at the start*/};
```

or

```
List<Athlete> athletes = new List<Athlete>();
athletes.Add(new BobSledder("Bobby", "Ben and Bill"));
...
```

This allows you to change the number of athletes at runtime a little easier.  It may also be easier to separate out each of the athletes by their sport, as opposed to holding them all in a single list/array since it may be cleaner or simpler in the end, but I'm not sure what your end goal is so I can't say for sure what way is better.  If this isn't the only place where you need to deal with the athletes according to their separate sports, you probably want to think about splitting them into separate lists, one for each sport.  Something to keep in mind at least.

Then you can simply use a foreach loop on athletes and find the top 3 with something like:

```
double minScore = 0;
double maxScore = 0;
double midScore = 0;

foreach(Athlete player in Athletes){
    if (player.averageScore >= minScore) {
        minScore = midScore;
        midScore = maxScore;
        maxScore = player.averageScore; 
    } else if (player.averageScore >= midScore)
        minScore = midScore;
        midScore = player.averageScore;
    } else if (player.averageScore >= minScore);
        minScore = player.averageScore;
    }
}
```

Although the above code will only find the top 3 scores out of all athletes, you can set up a set of scores unique to each of your sports and then filter them out by using something like

```
if(player.GetType() == typeof(Skier))
```

to determine which set you want to switch to.  I would still suggest splitting your athletes up by sport if you routinely need to deal with them in terms of only their sport, as it will make everything easier down the line.

If you split them up into separate lists, you can just make a function like:

```
private double[] getTopThreeScores(List<Athlete> inAthletes){
    //Use this instead of the min/max/mid and then access by the index
    double[3] topScores = new double{0.0,0.0,0.0};

    /*Loop from above, but switch out topScores[0] for minScore, topScores[1] for mid, etc.*/

    return topScores;
}
```

Hopefully this helps a bit.

Keeping the arrays:

```
private double[] getTopThreeScores(object inSport, Athlete[] inAthletes){
    Type sportType = inSport.GetType();
    double[3] topScores = new double{0.0,0.0,0.0};
    int length = inAthletes.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(inAthletes[i].GetType() == sportType){
            if (player.averageScore >= minScore) {
                minScore = midScore;
                midScore = maxScore;
                maxScore = player.averageScore; 
            } else if (player.averageScore >= midScore)
                minScore = midScore;
                midScore = player.averageScore;
            } else if (player.averageScore >= minScore);
                minScore = player.averageScore;
            }
        }
    }
    return topScores;
}
```

Would be called like

```
getTopThreeScores(new Skier(), athletes);
```

or you can pass in a specific athlete.

Not necessarily the cleanest way, but it will work and allows you to specify different types.  I haven't compiled this, so there may be some small errors.

Comment: You can do something similar with arrays, just use a standard for loop instead of the foreach.  Just simpler to use a list if you need to add things.  And if you have to keep the arrays as is, just use a type check to determine which set of scores you need to change and then change only those.  You can also just add the scores to a list for each sport, then do a sort on that and pull the top 3.

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> I want to be able to find the top 3 averageScores of each child type in the array.

So I propose the following solution:

```
var top3Skiers = athletes.OfType<Skier>()
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.AverageScore).Take(3);
```

As with other solutions, this requires the use of the `System.Linq` namespace to work.  [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will only select objects of the specified type, allowing you to filter out exactly what you want.  That means if you wanted to select the top 3 `IceSkater`s, you'd specify `OfType<IceSkater>()` instead.

In order to enumerate the results, you could `foreach` over them, like so:

```
foreach (var skier in top3Skiers)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", skier.Name, skier.AverageScore);
```